# Simple examples of order-preserving maps of preordered sets - not posets or directed sets?

Tags: order-theory

What are some simple examples of an order-preserving map $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ between preordered sets where at least one of $X$ or $Y$ is neither partially ordered nor directed by its preorder?

I ask because the definition and terminology of order-preserving maps are typically introduced for partially ordered sets, but exactly the same definition and terminology apply to directed sets. Since partial orderings and directions are both instances of preorderings, it is desirable to introduce the notion just once, for preorderings. However, it is not especially meaningful in a pedagogical sense to do so if the only simple and "good" examples are, in fact, for partial orderings and directions!

Comment: There are not really any interesting examples of preordered sets besides posets--a preordered set is just a poset where you have replaced each element by a set of "equivalent" elements.  I would go so far as to say that giving examples of preordered sets to illustrate anything _other_ than this point is bad pedagogy.

Comment: Directed sets are preordered sets that are not posets, yet they are interesting, e.g., as domains of nets, used to study of convergence.

Comment: Sure, there are some natural preordered sets that do not arise from starting with a poset.  But if you want to understand what they "look like", you still want to think of them as a poset with equivalent copies of elements.  In any case examples are trivial to come up with and it's not clear to me what your pedagogical goal with them is.

Comment: Pedagogical goal: to define "order-preserving map" just once, for preordered sets, so that the notion is available for both posets and directed sets -- but without just being pedantically abstract!

Answer (score 1):

As an order preserving map is defined between orders,
there are no order preserving maps between relations
that are not orders.

f:(X,R) -> (Y,S) is a relation preserving map when
R is relation for X, S is relation for Y, f:X -> Y
and for all x,y in X, (xRy implies f(x)S(y)).

For n, in the positive integers N, define
p(n) as the number of unique primes that divide n.
nPm when p(n) <= p(m) is a preorder.
nDm when n divides m is an order.

An example of a relation preserving map from an
order to a preorder is the identity map from 
(N,D) to (N,P).

Comment: I don't understand the import of the first paragraph, as I didn't ask about order-preserving maps except in the case of preordered sets. It makes perfectly good sense, it would seem, to use the term "order-preserving" even for a map between just preordered sets. Moreover, I don't know what you mean by an "order"; I know what is mean by "preorder" (aka "quasi-order"), "partial order", "total order", etc.

Comment: Isn't the relation $P$ a direction on $\mathbb{N}^{*}$ (the set of strictly positive integers)? After all, given $m, n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, let $k$ be, say, $m n j$ where $j$ is a product of some primes not appearing in the prime-power decomposition of either $m$ or $n$, and then $m P k$ and $n P k$.

Comment: An order, @murray, is a reflexive, asymmetric, transitive relation.

Comment: @murray.  P is not a direction, whatever that means.   (N,P) is up directed as well numerous subsets of N.

Comment: A reflexive, symmetric, transitive relation is usually called a *partial order", not simply an "order". A "direction" is a preorder (reflexive, transitive) with the additional property that, given any two elements of the set, there is some element of the set that succeeds both of them